# iOS Use Name of Array as Label text from plist

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

I currently have a plist file that looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Hello</key>
    <array/>
    <key>Hi</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

More keys can be added to this by the user. I need to be able to use those keys as the labels in a TableView. The TableView is ready and set up. I just need to be able to grab each array and use it for the label. How can I do this?

Comment: if you are able to change plist structure to Dictionary contains an array and that array contains other dictionaries , you can get each item from plist in order of your plist. first element Hello, second element hi and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load NSDictionary from plist, then get all keys with `[dictionary allKeys]` which returns an array of strings in your case. Please note, that dictionary does not save the order of keys. So if you want to show the same table every time, you have to save keys separately in array or sort them.

Comment: This is what I'm now doing in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:
`UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path];
        label.text = [[dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: ugh. This may work (but more likely this wouldn't work, as I said in my answer, allKeys doesn't guarantee the same order of keys on each call) but it's very ugly. DO NOT load dictionary on every cellForRowAtIndexPath call. This is very expensive. It's better to store [dictionary allKeys] as an NSArray property of a view controller (in viewDidLoad method for instance) and then use it.

Comment: Ok, I've added an ivar for my view controller which is `NSArray *viewerKeys`. in `viewDidLoad` I've added `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path];
    viewerKeys = [dictionary allKeys];` and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` contains `label.text = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row`. No joy

Comment: No crash, but my table isn't populated. Totally blank

Comment: Have you tried to do NSLog of the [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]? Are you sure label is not nil? Debug! :)

Comment: I'm getting a log from viewerKeys but nothing from objectAtIndex - not even nil